# How can i Parse JSON data values present at any level in GROOVY

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Following is my Parsed JSON with json Surplur . i has been required for SOAPUI scripts to manupulate

```
 {buildInfo={application=RepCatalog, buildDate=Thu Oct 13 17:01:48 IST 2016, version=1.0.0}, data={Reps=[{cascadeCount=0, catalogRep={RepId=48961, RepType=REPORT, initialCreation=10/13/2016 20:39:11, lastAccessed=10/13/2016 20:39:11, lastModified=10/13/2016 20:39:11, parentRep={RepId=48962, RepType=REPORT, initialCreation=10/13/2016 20:39:14, lastAccessed=10/13/2016 20:39:14, lastModified=10/13/2016 20:39:14, status=OPEN, title=REPORT1476371359504}, rights=[{availability=PUBLIC, isDefault=true}], status=OPEN, title=REPORT1476371357505, userTags=[PRIVATE1476371349835]}, status=success}]}, status=success, summary={apiName=Integration Service, partialRepSucceeded=0, totalRepFailed=0, totalRepProccessed=1, totalRepSucceeded=1}, time=6674}
```

Following is unparsed JSON

```
{
   "summary":    {
      "apiName": "Integration Service",
      "totalRepProccessed": 1,
      "totalRepFailed": 0,
      "totalRepSucceeded": 1,
      "partialRepSucceeded": 0
   },
   "buildInfo":    {
      "application": "RepCatalog",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "buildDate": "Thu Oct 13 17:01:48 IST 2016"
   },
   "status": "success",
   "data": {"Reps": [   {
      "status": "success",
      "catalogRep":       {
         "RepId": 48961,
         "RepType": "REPORT",
         "title": "REPORT1476371357505",
         "rights": [         {
            "availability": "PUBLIC",
            "isDefault": true
         }],
         "initialCreation": "10/13/2016 20:39:11",
         "lastModified": "10/13/2016 20:39:11",
         "lastAccessed": "10/13/2016 20:39:11",
         "status": "OPEN",
         "parentRep":          {
            "RepId": 48962,
            "RepType": "REPORT",
            "title": "REPORT1476371359504",
            "status": "OPEN"
         },
         "userTags": ["PRIVATE1476371349835"]
      },
      "cascadeCount": 0
   }]},
   "time": 6674
}
```

I want to parse it to get values of All RepId in above in groovy SOAPUI

Comment: Which `RepId`? The catalog one, or the parentRep one?

Comment: Values of All RepId of irrespective level it can present anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Given your input as a string variable called `json`, the following script:

```
def extractRepIds (def tree, def ids = []) {
    switch (tree) {
        case Map:
            tree.each { k, v ->
                if (k == "RepId") { ids << v }
                extractRepIds(v, ids)
            }
            return ids
        case Collection:
            tree.each { e -> extractRepIds(e, ids) }
            return ids
        default :
            return ids
    }
}

def extractRepIdsFromJson(def jsonString) {
    def tree = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
    extractRepIds(tree)
}

println extractRepIdsFromJson(json)
```

produces the following results:

```
[48961, 48962]
```

#### Alternate Solution

The `extractRepIds` method can be written somewhat more cleanly by using the `inject()` method:

```
def extractRepIds (def tree) {
    switch (tree) {
        case Map:
            return tree.inject([]) { list, k, v ->
                list + (k == "RepId" ? [v] : extractRepIds(v))
            }
        case Collection:
            return tree.inject([]) { list, e ->
                list + extractRepIds(e)
            }
        default :
            return []
    }
}
```

With all else being the same, this yields the same results.

Comment: This is very nice. May be another input argument(RepId in this case) can be passed to make it generic.

Comment: @Rao: Sure that would be an easy improvement.

Comment: @Abbas ALI: I'm not Tim (not even close). but thanks anyway. I'm flattered. Does that mean you will select my answer as correct (green check)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all occurrences in a file, you can use regular expressions. It may be useful in this case.

```
def pattern = ~'\"RepId\":\\s(\\d+)' //"RepId": 48961
def path = "/tmp/data.json"
def data = new File(path).text

def repIds = []
pattern.matcher(data).findAll{fullMatch,repId ->
    repIds << repId
}
```